# How to get pentaho dashboard tables row count popup alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-ctools

I have a table in my dashboard and I want to display how many rows it contains. Like javascript alert popup.

Note: It must display a popup on the loading dashboard with number of rows given table has.

So far i tried this, but it didn't work. I used these codes in preExecution.

```
function f(){

var rowCount = document.getElementById('myTableID').rows.length;

alert(rowCount);
}

&

function testClick(e) {

var id = e.tableData.rows.length;

alert(id);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read the document how to use pentaho popup.
I am giving over-view, take table component, write query for count.
use pentaho popup call the query component inside popup **OR** use bootstrap's box component and call your query on pageload event.